# Why a 'next' before 'complete' of Angular takeuntil ngUnsubscribe?

Tags: angular, rxjs

There are tons of info out there on using 'takeUntil' operator to unsubscribe from a stream, like so:

```js
...

export class CategoryOptionInputComponent 

constructor(private svc: MyService, protected router: RouterService) {

  ...
  
  this.router.routerUrl$.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)).subscribe(s => {
      const param1 = s.state.featureId;
      this.svc.InitFromApi(param1);
    });
    
   ...
  }
  
    ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();//<-- This line is confusing
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
  }
  
  private readonly ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();
  
}
```

As the above code shown, we needed to load data from API on router data being parsed, and continue to load new data when new router data arrives, until the component is destroyed.

When a user navigating to a different route, the component is expected to be destroyed without a last hit on the API. However it does not behave as expected. The call to API is made even if the component is about to be destroyed.

My questions are:

(1) How to prevent the component to hit the API before it dies?

(2) Why not just complete() the stream, why a next() call before complete() (see the above code)?

Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) If you want the API call to be cancelable it needs to be part of the observable chain. When the call is performed inside `subscribe` there's no way it can be canceled so you'll have to use an operator for this such as `mergeMap` or `concatMap`.

```
this.router.routerUrl$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
  concatMap(s => {
    const param1 = s.state.featureId;
    return this.svc.InitFromApi(param1);
  })
).subscribe();
```

However, this expects that `this.svc.InitFromApi()` returns an Observable or a Promise. If you subscribe inside `InitFromApi()` or use `then()` on a Promise then it makes in unsubscribable.

2) That's how `takeUntil` is designed. It only reacts to `next` notifications. If you don't want to call both `next()` and `complete()` you can use `defaultIfEmpty()` operator:

```
this.router.routerUrl$.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe.pipe(
    defaultIfEmpty(null),
  ))
).subscribe(...);
```

Then you can call just `this.ngUnsubscribe.complete()` it'll trigger `takeUntil` as well.

Actually, in your example you don't even need to call `complete()` if you call `next()` because the next notification will make the chain to dispose.