# Unsubscribe from Observable that doesn't emit anymore

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component containing a `Subject` which is only being used within that same component (`subscribe` is called by `ngOnInit`, `next` is called in the template) would it lead to memory leak when left subscribed?

Comment: Even if you could leave it subscribed, why not just unsubscribe in `ngOnDestroy`?

Comment: `@Heretic Monkey`  why unsubscribe if it's not necessary

Comment: Safety. So, right now, the component's `Subject` is not being used elsewhere. Next year, someone comes along and subscribes to it. Now you've got a memory leak you could have easily bypassed by simply unsubscribing in the first place. Up to you, of course, you know the risks better than I...

Comment: The best practice would be to complete the subject in the ngOnDestroy rather than manage any subscriptions.

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57009988/8578281

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the observable is created in the component they both fall into garbage collection at the same time. A leak only occurs if the component is subscribed to an observable that lives in another spot such as a service and has not fallen into garbage collection.