# Argument when using .next() with takeUntil

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've noticed recently after upgrading my rxjs version that you can't use the `.next()` method `this.ngUnsubscribe$.next();` as it is anymore as you would below:

```
export class TakeUntilComponent implements OnDestroy {
  // Our magical observable that will be passed to takeUntil()
  private readonly ngUnsubscribe$: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  // Our subject that we will subscribe to
  subjectA$: Subject<number> = new Subject<number>();

  constructor() {
    this.subjectA$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe$))
      .subscribe(value => {
      // logic goes here ...
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    // Emit a value so that takeUntil will handle the closing of our subscriptions;
    this.ngUnsubscribe$.next();
    // Unsubscribe from our unsubscriber to avoid creating a memory leak
    this.ngUnsubscribe$.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

But now you must send an argument to it like this:

```
this.ngUnsubscribe$.next(null);
```

or

```
this.ngUnsubscribe$.next(true);
```

My question is why? And what value would you know to send?

Comment: Does `this.ngUnsubscribe$.next();` give you an error?

Comment: Which version of RxJS are you using? For me it still works with version 6.6.0

Comment: It should also work with rxjs 7 https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/6324

Comment: Ah I'm using "rxjs": "^7.2.0".  Error I get is: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
Subject.d.ts(31, 10): An argument for 'value' was not provided.
(method) Subject<any>.next(value: any): void
No quick fixes available

Comment: Why does it show you `Subject<any>` instead of `Subject<void>`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57007118/do-i-need-to-complete-takeuntil-subject-inside-ngondestroy

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're defining your Subject as `Subject<void>`. Calling `next()` wants to emit `undefined`.

So you should call `this.ngUnsubscribe$.next(void 0)` instead.

Comment: Is there a difference to doing that compared with this.ngUnsubscribe$.next(null); ?

Comment: `null` is a type in TypeScript so depending on your tsconfig you need to specifically that a variable can have `null` type. So using `next(null)` and `next(void 0)` are two different calls.

Comment: Cool thanks. Any idea as to why this error only occurred after upgrading my rxjs?

Comment: Well they changed typings for `next()`

Comment: Ah I see thanks. Always scary when upgrading all my packages in my project something always breaks.

Comment: @martin: Would there be any difference here to use `next(undefined)`?

Answer (score 17):

This happens after upgrading rxjs version to 7 from 6

**Rxjs 7 changes**

After checking the changelog and several github issues about this situation,

> Subject: resolve issue where Subject constructor errantly allowed an argument (#5476) (e1d35dc)

> Subject: no default generic (e678e81)

[Changelog 7.0.0-beta.1](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#700-beta1-2020-07-02) and [the commit where empty value is removed from the tests](https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/commit/e678e81ba80f5bcc27b0e956295ce2fc8dfe4576#diff-c876f4a80a0bc2ad8a1f2e5aff377f2bd024c32400f6967913bf41c532434391)

[image]

I realized that the solution was to either provide a value or simply typecast the `Subject` with `<void>` (as [@martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68543295/5706293) also said) as in `destroy$ = new Subject<void>()` if you want to `next` it with an empty value.

My related post: [rxjs 7 update - Subject - Expected 1 arguments, but got 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68590899/rxjs-7-update-subject-expected-1-arguments-but-got-0/68590900#68590900)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to fix this would be to use the ng-neat npm package:
https://github.com/ngneat/until-destroy

Just by adding `@UntilDestroy({ checkProperties: true })` to the top of your class you can remove all the takeUntils(this.unsubscribe) out of the code and remove the ngOnDestroy method. Just think it looks a lot cleaner and you will have less imports.