# rxjs 7 update - Subject - Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I updated rxjs from version 6.x.x to 7.x.x, but following error appeared:

> Error in src/app/app.component.ts (12:19)
> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.

when trying to `next` an empty value to the `Subject`

```js
destroy$ = new Subject();

constructor() {
  this.destroy$.next(); // <-- Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
}
```

[Error stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xhxbmy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/6324 or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68543205/argument-when-using-next-with-takeuntil

Comment: @martin I was searching everywhere for this question! Thanks!, I'll duplicate this and provide an answer there. I think this title is more generic for people to find

Answer (score 97, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

Either indicate the type explicitly with `void`:

```js
new Subject<void>();
```

or pass a fake value:

```js
this.destroy$.next(true);
```

**Rxjs 7 changes**

After checking the changelog and several github issues about this situation,

> Subject: resolve issue where Subject constructor errantly allowed an argument (#5476) (e1d35dc)

> Subject: no default generic (e678e81)

[Changelog 7.0.0-beta.1](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#700-beta1-2020-07-02) and [the commit where empty value is removed from the tests](https://github.com/reactivex/rxjs/commit/e678e81ba80f5bcc27b0e956295ce2fc8dfe4576#diff-c876f4a80a0bc2ad8a1f2e5aff377f2bd024c32400f6967913bf41c532434391)

[image]

I realized that the solution was to either provide a value or simply typecast the `Subject` with `<void>` as in `destroy$ = new Subject<void>()` if you want to `next` it with an empty value.

Comment: In my case passing fake value works but typecast does not solve this issue.

Comment: what seems to be the issue with typecasting? do you see any errors?

Comment: I don't think it's really "typecasting", it just providing the type of the Subject in TypeScript explicitly. In this case `void`.